# Ember: Unable to get model in controller init function

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a ember application whose route, controller are as follows:

```
//Route
model:function(){
    return this.store.getJSON('object/');
},
setupController:function(controller, model){
    controller.set('content', model)
}


//controller
init:function(){
    this.myfunction();
},
myfunction:function(){
  var content = this.get('content')
  console.log(content.length)
}
```

myfunction gets executed when the page/template is loaded and it returns "cannot read property of null" . I am unable to get route model in controller init function.

Comment: This has to do with the way controllers are setup relative to routes. By the time `setupController` has been called in your route, your controller has already been `init`-ed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` is not referring to the the controller because of the way you called `myfunction`. In your controller, `myfunction` should be an action:

```
init() {
  this.send('myfunction');
},
actions: {
  myfunction: function() {
    var content = this.get('content');
    console.log(content.length);
  }
}
```